# Taking a screenshot from a web application

Tags: javascript, web-applications, applet, activex, screenshot

I need to create a web application that can take screenshot from any window (not only the current browser, it can be another window). So, through javascript/html is not possible, but I think it can be possible by using ActiveX or a Java Applet, maybe?

Anyone has any experience on this?

Thanks

Comment: So your web app should have information of all the browsers running on that computer? Or user? Or desktop? Or...?

Comment: Actually it should be able to take screenshots from any window of the OS (actually Windows)

Comment: Actually this is possible with HTML5 if I remembered it correctly.

Comment: This can be done with `.getUserMedia` in HTML5 (only Chrome supports it): https://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/getusermedia/screenshare.html

Comment: Oh but most of the users use IE